# Google cloud storage object returned "Service Unavailable" for just 1 particular file

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We store some of our sql files in storage, and load them to execute from time to time.

Today at some moment one of those files became 503 Service Unavailable.

The interesting part is that we have few of these files in one folder, and the rest were ok, except this one.

Is this google side issue, if so, what are guarantees that this won't happen again?

I can provide more detailed information to a google guy if needed, the project id, and the files, and the logs etc.

[image: Service Unavailable for particular file]